# Changing the height of a div using a rails instance variable

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails instance variable

For example:
`@meter_height`

I want to use that variable to adjust the height of a div

For example:
`<div style="height: <%= @meter_height %>"></div>`

However the height of the div does not get adjusted, it remains 0.

How do I change the height of the div using the rails instance variable?

Comment: You do it exactly as you're doing it, but if the instance variable contains only a number (ie `100`) then you need to add a unit, for example `px` or `%`.

Comment: Thank you @meagar! I used the unit earlier but turns out the problem was that I had a space between the unit and the variable, i.e. %> px; I removed the spacing and now it works i.e.  %>px;

Comment: @user229044 As a mod you should know you don't close a question `Not suitable for this site` when it most certainly is a programming question with enough scope and depth for you to answer it with a programming answer as your comment your shows exactly why this was not working. It was invalid CSS being generated,

Comment: @Barkermn01 My comment was a guess, based on an insufficiently specified question. It contains no output, and no input.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer as provided by user229044 in the comments:

`<div style="height: <%= @meter_height %>"></div>`

This is correct for outputting the variable however your constructed CSS is invalid CSS your not providing the unit type of `@meter_height` that CSS needs E.G `px`, so you should use something like

`<div style="height: <%= @meter_height %>px;"></div>`